# SIMPLE SQL Select Where Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Anyone got any idea why this doesn't work. Im at a loss

[image]

The following

```
SELECT * FROM  tblCustomerDetails WHERE AccountNo='STO00900'
```

Returns nothing however if i run the same query with any othe accoutn number it works.

and this account will show when i run

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tblCustomerDetails ORDER BY ID desc
```

Picture explains it better.

Thanks

Comment: Try copying and pasting from that cell in the result set into your first select. It could be some other char in there like a space that's not visible, and depending on your connection/DB settings the space may matter.

Comment: Try with like please, like this SELECT * FROM  tblCustomerDetails WHERE AccountNo like '%STO00900%'

Comment: @ThanosMarkou I think you mean `AccountNo LIKE '%STO00900%'`

Comment: @JNK yes sorry for the typo.

Comment: I did originally try C+P that cell into the query and it didnt work. SELECT LIKE did work, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM  tblCustomerDetails WHERE AccountNo LIKE '%STO00900%'
```

As there can be hidden characters.

Comment: If this works, fix your db content, bearing in mind this could find more than you want and is liable to be slower than a simple equality

Answer (score 2):

Try as Notulysses suggested, but I would recommend it a bit differently:

```
SELECT * FROM  tblCustomerDetails WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(AccountNo)) = 'STO00900'
```

The `LIKE` operator will likely match more rows than you need (if te `AccountNo` column is not unique), so I'd go with trimming the whitespaces and then checking for a specific account.

Comment: damn your were to fast for me :D

Answer (score 2):

There may be some space in the entry either in the start or at the end ,try to trim both ends of the entry.